# Why can Matrix Matrix Multiplication achieve better performance than Matrix Vector Multiplication?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory

According to some high performance computing books, some authors claim that the matrix-matrix multiplication can achieve better performance than matrix-vector multiplicatino in terms of the memory bandwidth. It seems that the matrix-matrix multiplication processes O(N^3) computation operations and O(N^2) data transfer operations. I do not know why we can have tremendous optimization potential in such case.

For example, if I want to compute the result of A*B*y, where A and B are n x n matrixes and y is a n x 1 vector. There are two ways that I can get the final result. First of all, I can compute the A*B first and get another new n by n matrix. After that, I can do the multiplication between matrix and vector. On the other hand, I can do two times matrix-vector multiplication. Which one is better?

Comment: Interesting topic. You should provide some more info on those claims, maybe a reference? Also, it would be interesting if you showed us some benchmark results.

Comment: http://prdrklaina.weebly.com/uploads/5/7/7/3/5773421/introduction_to_high_performance_computing_for_scientists_and_engineers.pdf This book claims in section 3.5.3

Comment: Instead of splitting up b:=ABy into 2 operations and saving a temporary, you might do it directly. For instance: b_j = sum_i A(j,:)*B(i,:)*y(i)

Comment: Also, you might want to post this in Computational Science.